# Prove that if $f:A\to B$ is bijective then $f^{-1}:B\to A$ is bijective.

Tags: functions

> Prove that if $f:A\to B$ is bijective then $f^{-1}:B\to A$ is bijective.

My approach:

Since $f$ is bijective, $f$ is surjective. That is, for all $b\in B$, there exists an $a \in A$ such that $f(a)=b$, so the range of $f$ is $B$. Also, the domain of $f$ is $A$. Since $f$ is a function, for all $x\in A$, $x$ corresponds to only a single $y \in B$. So given $f^{-1}:B\to A$, $f^{-1}(x)=f^{-1}(y) \implies x=y$, hence $f^{-1}$ is injective.

From here, I have trouble showing that $f^{-1}$ is surjective. I want to show that the range of $f^{-1}$ is $A$. How can I claim this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$f:A\to B$ is surjective means $f^{-1}:B\to A$ can be defined for the whole domain $B$. $f:A\to B$ is injective means $f^{-1}:B\to A$ is a well-defined *function*.

The injectivity of $f^{-1}$ follows from the fact that $f:A\to B$ is a well-defined function (if $f^{-1}(b_1)=a$ and $f^{-1}(b_2)=a$, what does this say about $f(a)$?). The surjectivity of $f^{-1}$ follows because $f$ is defined for the whole domain $A$ and $f$ is injective: for any $a\in A$, we have $f^{-1}(f(a))=a$.